# How can i display embedded videos side by side in html w/ spacing

Tags: html, video, embed

]if I try the flex or justify content my videos are either stacked or horizontal without spacing. code below:

```
    <div class="site-section py-5 bg-warning">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
          <div class="col-md-12 d-flex">
          <h2 class="text-white m-0">Videos</h2>
          <div class="col-md-3 mb-4">
            <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>
<div style=”float:left”>
</div>
  <iframe frameborder="0" id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xIgPMguqyws" title="YouTube video player" width="430" height="241" class="graphic"></iframe>
</div>                  
    <iframe frameborder="0" id="youtube" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/xIgPMguqyws" title="YouTube video player" width="430" height="241" class="graphic"></iframe>
</div>
</body>
```

[image]

Comment: `iframe{
  display:inline-block;
  margin-right:20px;
}`
Try adding this to your css and tell if it helped. And do notice, that is the screen is small enough they will stack under each other

Comment: hey jay-unfort it didnt change the layout. still stacked on top. Yup, my container spans the width of page and i'm currently viewing on browser.

Comment: Can you show desired result? I start to think I misunderstood you

Comment: nah if anything i butchered the explanation. So I was able to place videos adjacent using <div style=”float:left”> but now im stuck with spacing issue. Sample youtube vids in photo for description

Comment: Please don't add your code editor/IDE as a question tag unless the question is actually *about* the editor.